# Where to find detailed information about stock?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, volatility

The typical information about stock is historical prices, volatility and similar metrics that can be easily found.  However, where can one found reliable information about the number of issued stock, the voting rights, if there is more than one kind of stock for a given company, if the dividends are always paid, etc. In summary all the legal and formal details of a given stock.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Most of the information you want can be found in the **annual report** of the company. Go to their official website, look for shareholders information and then download the annual report. This will answer:
"*number of issued stock, voting rights, if there is more than one kind of stock, etc. In summary all the legal and formal details of a given stock*.

**2.** After reading the annual report, check on investors websites to see if you can find **analyst reports** written on this company. You can sometimes find them in some free newsletters. These reports will complete the information you have found in the annual report like "*if the dividends are always paid, etc.*"

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar.shtml) (Electronic Data Gathering, Analysis, and Retrieval), a big database run by the SEC where

> all companies, foreign and domestic, are required to file registration statements, periodic reports, and other forms electronically.